# How to calculate difference between 2 time columns in distinct tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to calculate the difference between EntryHourSchedule (the ideal time) and EntryHourRegistered (the real time) of a worker's assitance, but both are in 2 different tables: ScheduleDetail (* to 1 with Schedule) and Registry.

I used

```
datediff(second, start_date, end_date) / 3600.0
```

for calculate this with the next [tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uw5Td.jpg).

Just like this:

```sql
SELECT I.IdTrabajador, I.Fecha
    , Datediff(second
        , I.HoraInicioRefrigerio
        , (SELECT HD.HoraInicioRefrigerio
            FROM [rrhh].TrabajadorHorarioDetalle HD INNER JOIN [rrhh].TrabajadorHorario H
                ON HD.IdTrabajadorHorario = H.IdTrabajadorHorario
            WHERE H.Estado = 1 AND HD.Estado = 1 AND HD.Dia = (SELECT Datename(dw, I.Fecha))
            )
        ) / 3600.0 as Cantidad
    , 0.00 as Costo
FROM [rrhh].TrabajadorIncidencia I
```

But result in an Error: **The subquery has returned more than one value, which is not correct when it goes after =,! =, <, <=,>,> = Or when it is used as an expression.**

Finally, it should be shown, for example: `IdTrabajador: 1 | Fecha: '2019-01-29' | Cantidad: 1.5`

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like you should be joining the outer table to make it a correlated subquery.

Comment: The problem is that you have two martes lines. Both line 1 and 7 in your first query in the image, line up with the 3 line in the image so it doesn't know which to pick

Comment: How I should do it? Thanks

Comment: @user1178830 but 'Martes' in line 7 is for another IdTrabajador

Comment: Aside: `(SELECT Datename(dw, I.Fecha))` is interesting. Why not simply `Datename(dw, I.Fecha)`? Tip: Reasons not to use images are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546).

Comment: Thanks, I will try to ask questions in this format.

Comment: @HABO About ````select Datename...````, it works the same :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the link on IdTrabajador in your subquery:

```
SELECT I.IdTrabajador, I.Fecha
    , Datediff(second
        , I.HoraInicioRefrigerio
        , (SELECT HD.HoraInicioRefrigerio
            FROM [rrhh].TrabajadorHorarioDetalle HD INNER JOIN [rrhh].TrabajadorHorario H
                ON HD.IdTrabajadorHorario = H.IdTrabajadorHorario
            WHERE H.Estado = 1 AND HD.Estado = 1 AND HD.IdTrabajador = I.IdTrabajador AND HD.Dia = (SELECT Datename(dw, I.Fecha))
            )
        ) / 3600.0 as Cantidad
    , 0.00 as Costo
FROM [rrhh].TrabajadorIncidencia I
```